# Devise Invitable - Restricting Access to Only invited users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-invitable

I might be searching the wrong key words, but I can't find a way to only restrict users that are invited to be allowed to create an account on my rails site (or maybe I'm using devise-invitable wrong). I assume, there should be a method I call in the before filter or flip the switch on the initializer/devise.rb

I tried in my **users_controller.rb** and had no luck using Ruby Doc as [reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/l/lperichon-devise_invitable-0.3.0/Devise/Models/Invitable.html#method-i-invited-3F)

```
before_filter: invited?
```

I have read the initializers/devise.rb and the readme and didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I didnt think of the obvious. Restrict users via devise with the routes, not devise-invitable.

Used [Solution #2](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) as a reference *(see below)*

Lets suppose that you don't want to allow to sign up but you want to allow to change password for registered users. Just paste this code in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          
    as :user do
      get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
      put 'users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
    end
```

And then you can make such link in your view:

```
= link_to "Change your password", edit_user_registration_path
```

Notice: you will need to update default devise views accordingly, i.e. in `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` change `registration_path(resource_name)` to `user_registration_path(resource)` (If using shared views for multiple models, you can use `send("#{resource_name}_registration_path", resource))`

Notice: If you are using rails 4.0+ you should be using patch instead of put for updates. You should change the method in the form_tag residing in `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` and the `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should make custom filter for this purpose.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

before_filter :restrict_only_invited_users

def restrict_only_invited_users
  redirect_to :root if current_user.invitation_accepted_at.blank?
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I might consider in place or with my routes fix.

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up going with the suggested option that devise had.